# JSF / hibernate hql no muestra resultados

Tags: hibernate

Tengo un HQL para extraer datos de una tabla que tienen el mismo ID del usuario al que estoy haciendo clic

mi frijol es:

```
public void setViewUser () throws IOException {

    UserDAOImpl dao = new UserDAOImpl();  

    User user = dao.findById(id_user);
    id_user = user.getId_user();
    nom = user.getNom();
    prenom = user.getPrenom();
    mail = user.getMail();
    dette = user.getDette();
    telephone = user.getTelephone();
    adressePostal =user.getAdressePostal();
    nombre_objet_reserve = user.getNombre_objet_reserve();
    nombre_objet_loue =user.getNombre_objet_loue();  
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("Compte_client.xhtml");

}

private serviceMethods serviceMethods = new serviceMethods();
List<Pl> list = serviceMethods.ListPl(id_user);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Pl> pllist = (List<Pl>)(Object) list;
```

y mi serviceMethods es:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Pl> ListPl(Integer id) {

                String queryString = "from Pl f where f.user= :id) ";

             Session sess = HibernateUtil.openSession();
             Query query = sess.createQuery(queryString);
             query.setParameter("id", id);
             List<Pl> listObject = (List<Pl>) query.list();
              sess.getTransaction();
              sess.close();
              return listObject;

            }
```

my xhtml is:

```
<h:dataTable class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0" value="#{AffichUserBean.pllist}" var="t">

        <h:column><f:facet name="header">idres</f:facet>#{t.coutFinal}</h:column>

      <h:column><f:facet name="header">deadline</f:facet>#{t.caution_produit}</h:column>
         <h:column><f:facet name="header">defauts</f:facet>#{t.defauts}</h:column>


          </h:dataTable>
```

Obtengo el hql en la consola pero solo obtengo el resultado para el segundo y no el primero:

> 2018-03-19T15:12:39.633+0100|Infos: Hibernate: select pl0_.num_serie as num_seri1_1_, pl0_.idproduit as idprodui2_1_,
>   pl0_.id_user as id_user3_1_, pl0_.date_debut_location as date_deb4_1_,
>   pl0_.date_fin_location as date_fin5_1_, pl0_.defauts as defauts6_1_,
>   pl0_.reserve as reserve7_1_, pl0_.prix_location_jour as prix_loc8_1_,
>   pl0_.caution_produit as caution_9_1_, pl0_.del as del10_1_ from pl
>   pl0_ where pl0_.id_user=?
>
> 2018-03-19T15:12:39.651+0100|Infos: Hibernate: select user0_.id_user as id_user1_4_0_, user0_.nom as nom2_4_0_, user0_.mail
>   as mail3_4_0_, user0_.password as password4_4_0_, user0_.dette as
>   dette5_4_0_, user0_.photo as photo6_4_0_, user0_.telephone as
>   telephon7_4_0_, user0_.prenom as prenom8_4_0_, user0_.adresse_postale
>   as adresse_9_4_0_, user0_.nombre_objet_reserve as nombre_10_4_0_,
>   user0_.nombre_objet_loue as nombre_11_4_0_ from user user0_ where
>   user0_.id_user=?

el mapeo de la primera entidad

```
  <meta attribute = "class-description">
     This class contains the user detail. 
  </meta>

  <id name = "id_user" type = "int" column = "id_user">
         <generator class="increment" />

  </id>

  <property name = "nom" column = "nom" type = "string"/>
  <property name = "mail" column = "mail" type = "string"/>
  <property name = "password" column = "password" type = "string"/>
  <property name = "dette" column = "dette" type = "int"/>
  <property name = "photo" column = "photo" type = "string"/>
  <property name = "telephone" column = "telephone" type = "string"/>
  <property name = "prenom" column = "prenom" type = "string"/>
  <property name = "adressePostal" column = "adresse_postale" type = "string"/>
  <property name = "nombre_objet_reserve" column = "nombre_objet_reserve" type = "int"/>
  <property name = "nombre_objet_loue" column = "nombre_objet_loue" type = "int"/>
```

el mapeo de la segunda entidad

```
<id name = "num_serie" type = "int" column = "num_serie">
         <generator class="increment" />

  </id>

   <many-to-one name="produit_loue" class="com.serveurweb.location.doa.entities.Produit"
        column="idproduit" unique="true"  lazy ="false" not-null="true"
        cascade="all" />
   <many-to-one name="user" class="com.serveurweb.location.doa.entities.User"
        column="id_user" unique="true" lazy ="false" not-null="true"
        cascade="all" />

   <property name = "date_debut_location" column = "date_debut_location" type = "date"/>
   <property name = "date_fin_location" column = "date_fin_location" type = "date"/>
   <property name = "defauts" column = "defauts" type = "string"/>
   <property name = "reserve" column = "reserve" type = "int"/>
   <property name = "prix_location_jour" column = "prix_location_jour" type = "int"/>
   <property name = "caution_produit" column = "caution_produit" type = "int"/>
   <property name = "del" column = "del" type = "int"/>
```

No sé, pero cuando intento la consulta con un número de identificación, obtengo el resultado que deseo, pero cuando uso: id no obtengo resultados.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
 session.getTransaction().begin(); 
 Query query = session.createQuery("from Pl f where f.user.id_user= 3");
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
 List<Pl>pl = (List<Pl>) query.list(); 
 for(Pl l : pl) System.out.println(l.getNum_serie()); 
 session.getTransaction().commit();
 HibernateUtil.close();}
```

Comment: Podrias mostrar como se estan mapeadas las dos tablas

Comment: @RaulCacacho Si

Comment: Si al obtener los datos ya ves que no te devuelve los que tocan ¿qué tiene que ver JSF con todo esto?

Comment: @Marine1 pero no obienes los datos que deseas podrias explicar un poco mas eso es un poco confuso

Comment: @RaulCacacho cuando hago clic en un usuario quiero tener el pl correspondiente a este usuario, pero incluso si la consulta hql funciona, no tengo resultados / los campos permanecen vacíos después de la ejecución del código

Comment: @Marine1 esta es la lista que quieres llenarAffichUserBean.pllist

Comment: No quiero llenar esta lista, pero quiero recuperar los datos de ella